# How to split Excel cell into multiple rows based on Comma delimination

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I have a semi large data set (50K+ rows) that I am working with containing over 19 columns. What I need to accomplish is split certain instances where one cell in a particular column (in the image example its **Org**) has multiple items separated by a comma as shown below and simply repeat the entire row and only retain the new value after the comma. I've been doing this manually but of course it is absurd to do this in this manner.

[image: Mock data]

I was wondering it is possible to do it without VBA but I am willing to try a VBA solution and try to explain it to my higher ups. It contains 19 columns and not all values in other columns are filled but the "Org" does contain values in every cell.

Also glad to have joined this wonderful community and thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you saying you would have 3 lines for cell F3?  One for each item?

Comment: Yes I would have three rows for Cell F3 as there are three values there total

Comment: I like the answer provided below for a non-VBA solution.  If you are going to prepare the data for the folks in your organization, it will work.  If they are going to transform the data it may not be as practical.  If you want a VBA solution, the way this site works is that you try some code and others help problem solve or improve.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution using formula only.

[image: Image shown here.]

Cell `M1` is the delimiter. In this case a comma.

```
Helper:=SUM(K1,LEN(B1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B1,$N$1,"")))+1
```

You must fill the above formula down one row more.

```
A8:=a1
```

Fill this formula to the right.

```
A9:=LOOKUP(ROW(1:1),$J:$J,A:A)
```

Fill this formula to the right and down.

```
F9:=MID($M$1&LOOKUP(ROW(A1),$J:$J,F:F)&$M$1,FIND("艹",SUBSTITUTE($M$1&LOOKUP(ROW(A1),$J:$J,F:F)&$M$1,$M$1,"艹",ROW(A2)-LOOKUP(ROW(A1),$J:$J)))+1,FIND("艹",SUBSTITUTE($M$1&LOOKUP(ROW(A1),$J:$J,F:F)&$M$1,$M$1,"艹",ROW(A2)-LOOKUP(ROW(A1),$J:$J)+1))-FIND("艹",SUBSTITUTE($M$1&LOOKUP(ROW(A1),$J:$J,F:F)&$M$1,$M$1,"艹",ROW(A2)-LOOKUP(ROW(A1),$J:$J)))-1)
```

Fill down.

Bug:

Blank cells will be filled with 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Power Query for that. Move the Org column to the very right, then split by each comma, then select the split Org columns and click "unpivot" on the ribbon. No code, just clicking icons, and it's repeatable. If the source data changes, just refresh the query.

In the screenshot, the source data (simplified) is the blue table, and the Power Query result is the green table.

Power Query is a free add-in from Microsoft for Excel 2010 and 2013 and built into Excel 2016 as Get and Transform.

[image]

Comment: This is so amazing and would love to have been able to use it but unfortunately my company prohibits from using extension not already provided with excel. But this method would solve my problem wonderfully

Comment: Convince your company to add Power Query to the standard build. I convinced my IT department, too. Show them this. Do a little bit of research about Power Query and you'll find that it's the best thing added to Excel in 20 years.

Comment: I have successfully installed the power pivot tool and will be attempting this method. Thank you so much for the help and ill report back if I am successful.

Comment: I meant to say Power Query, I requested that software addon and will be checking it out once it gets approved.